# Can Mongo config servers have different user privilages in each of them?

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

I found out recently that the set of privileges that users have are not the same in all the 3 config servers. Some users don't even exist in one of the config server. When creating a user don't they all have same set of replica for the 3 config servers?

How can i Fix this?

Answer (score 2):

use db.createUser() to create an user.

use db.grantRolesToUser() to assign privileges to the user.

**Reference:** [mongoDB Privileges](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/security/) , [create user](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#db.createUser), [grant privilege](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/#db.grantRolesToUser)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I have done the same thing to add users, somehow its not creating the same metadata for that user in all three config servers. Hope you understood my question in first place!